# View array in Visual Studio debugger?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, arrays, view, debugging

Is it possible to view an array in the Visual Studio debugger?  QuickWatch only shows the first element of the array.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/198953

Comment: If it is a CArray, writing array.m_pData[pos] or array->m_pData[pos] (depending on the case) on the Watch Window lets you see the contents of array at the pos position!

Answer (score 673, accepted):

You can try this nice little trick for C++.  Take the expression which gives you the array and then append a comma and the number of elements you want to see.  Expanding that value will show you elements 0-(N-1) where N is the number you add after the comma.

For example if `pArray` is the array, type `pArray,10` in the watch window.

Comment: Incredible find. It does however only work with immediate values, no arithmetic or dynamic member access is allowed.

Comment: Note that you can also use a cast in the debug view. If `pArray` is of type `void*` you can type `(char*) pArray, 10` which will display the content of the array interpreted as char.

Comment: Cannot do this in Visual Studio 2008 Express. If I add an expression "a+1,2" in the Watch Window, the foloowing error will occur:    "error: + cannot be performed on 'pArray' and '1'". What version of VS are you using?

Comment: Anyone know if something similar is available in Eclipse?

Comment: I think you're probably using GDB as the debugger in Eclipse, in which case the equivalent syntax, `*pArray@10` is what you're looking for.  I haven't tried it in Eclipse, but it works in command-line GDB.

Comment: what about c# ?

Comment: I don't think this is possible in c#, unfortunately. VS uses a far more robust set of format specifiers for c++ than it does for c# for some reason. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/format-specifiers-in-csharp?view=vs-2019

Comment: Oh wow, this is amazing. I can finally even debug old MFC arrays by using the arr.m_pData,n to show the n first items via their internal data structure! If I had only known this trick 10 years ago...

Answer (score 99):

If you have a large array and only want to see a subsection of the array you can type this into the watch window;

```
ptr+100,10
```

to show a list of the 10 elements starting at ptr[100]. Beware that the displayed array subscripts will start at [0], so you will have to remember that ptr[0] is really ptr[100] and ptr[1] is ptr[101] etc.

Answer (score 27):

I use the ArrayDebugView add-in for Visual Studio (http://arraydebugview.sourceforge.net/).

It seems to be a long dead project (but one I'm looking at continuing myself) but the add-in still works beautifully for me in VS2010 for both C++ and C#.

It has a few quirks (tab order, modal dialog, no close button) but the ability to plot the contents of an array in a graph more than make up for it.

Edit July 2014: I have finally built a new Visual Studio extension to replace ArrayebugView's functionality. It is available on the VIsual Studio Gallery, search for ArrayPlotter or go to http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2fde2c3c-5b83-4d2a-a71e-5fdd83ce6b96?SRC=Home

Comment: Looks great but doesnt support VS2013?? VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products. Supported Products : 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
Version : [10.0]
Version : [11.0]
Version : [12.0]
Version : [14.0]

Comment: It should do! I developed it in VS2013! What version of VS2013 (service pack / edition) are you running?

If you search for ArrayPlotter in the Extension Manager (in the Online section) do you see it available within there?

Comment: Beautiful tool, works fine for me in VS2013.

Answer (score 20):

Are you trying to view an array with memory allocated dynamically? If not, you can view an array for C++ and C# by putting it in the watch window in the debugger, with its contents visible when you expand the array on the little (+) in the watch window by a left mouse-click.

If it's a pointer to a dynamically allocated array, to view N contents of the pointer, type "pointer, N" in the watch window of the debugger. Note, N must be an integer or the debugger will give you an error saying it can't access the contents. Then, left click on the little (+) icon that appears to view the contents.

Answer (score -1):

Hover your mouse cursor over the name of the array, then hover over the little (+) icon that appears.

Comment: For C++ this will only show you the first element