# Visual C++ 2008: debugging data behind pointer array

Tags: c++, debugging, pointers

How can I see data behind a pointer to an array more than the first item in Visual Studio 2008? It would be so useful to see arbitrary amount of items, not just the first one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [View array in Visual Studio debugger?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972511/view-array-in-visual-studio-debugger)

Answer (score 10):

char* p = new char[100];

Type in the Watch window:

p, 100

Comment: If your array is quite long, you can also add an offset to see the N positions after the n-t, with (p+n),N.  See [http://support.microsoft.com/kb/198953/en-us](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/198953/en-us).

Answer (score 4):

To expand on Alex's answer (and maybe get myself a few more votes :) ), [here is the full list of debugger window format specifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75w45ekt.aspx).