# View array in Visual Studio debugger?

Tags: c++, c, cuda

my question is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972511/view-array-in-visual-studio-debugger)
the solution provided in the above does not work when using Nsight as a debugger.
how can i view all the elements of an array inside a kernel when using Nsight as a debugger?
QuickWhatch only shows the first 4 elements of the array!

Comment: It is a duplicate, the problem is the same.  The size of a C array is undiscoverable at runtime, both by your code and by the debugger.  Use the std::vector<> or TR1 std::array<> classes whenever you can.

Comment: possible duplicate of [View array in Visual Studio debugger?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972511/view-array-in-visual-studio-debugger)

Comment: but i just stated why it is not a duplicate!! its not the same case. i am using nsight to debug and not visual studio debugger...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of elements NSight will copy to the host for debugging is set in:

Nsight->Nsight Options->Debugger->Max Array elements

The default is 4, which is why you only see 4 elements. Increase this (and restart your debugging session), and you will be fine.