# Why does the debugger show only one element from my array pointer?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, malloc, new-operator

First off: I know that `new` is the C++ way of doing this. I am simply showing that there is more than one way to reproduce this error, and both are incredibly frustrating.

I have two forms of this source file. I'm trying to debug yet another programming assignment, but I'm not asking for help on that. Basically, I'm trying to re-implement `set` as a class with fields for size and a pointer to an `int` array. Here's the code using `new`:

testnew.cpp

```
int main()
{
    int size = 1;
    int *elements = new int[size];
    elements[0] = 0;
    size++;
    int * temp = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < (size - 1); i++)
    {
        temp[i] = elements[i];
    }
    delete[] elements;
    temp[size] = size;
    elements = temp;
    elements[1] = 1;
    delete[] elements;
}
```

and again, using the less-preferable `alloc` functions:

testalloc.cpp

```
int main()
{
    int size = 1;
    int * elements = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
    elements[0] = 0;
    size++;
    elements =(int *) realloc(elements,size * sizeof(int));
    elements[1] = 1;
    free(elements);
}
```

In both cases, my goal is to create an array, and then append to it. However, in both cases, after building and running it in Visual Studio 2010, **the array is not grown at all, and only has 1 "slot" for my items to go into**. In VS's debugger, I have watches on the `elements` array pointer; attached is a screenshot. It is the same for both versions of the code.

[image: My watches at the end of the program]

-- the breakpoint is at the `delete[]`/`free()` call.

Seriously, what am I doing wrong? This has to be a logic error, and I've combed through a quarter dozen examples of both `malloc`/`realloc` and `new`, and read and re-read my textbook, and I can't see what's wrong!

I feel like I should have a line that splits the allocated memory into an array, but doesn't the `new int[]` call do that?

Answer (score 5):

*Besides* any other issues with the code, you must either do what [JoeG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9671682/1441) mentions and have multiple watches, or set a watch like this:

```
elements,5
```

will result in:

[image]

I don't know if there is an updated list for VS2010, but this still works:
[Symbols for Watch Variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265753(v=vs.60).aspx?ppud=4)
And:
[View array in Visual Studio debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972511/view-array-in-visual-studio-debugger)

Answer (score 4):

Other answers have pointed out the bug in your code (`temp[size] = size;`), however your confusion is coming from the fact that you're misreading the debugger's output.

As far as the type system and debugger are concerned, `elements` isn't an array,  it's a pointer. The debugger has no way of knowing whether or not it's a pointer to the first element in an array or a pointer to a single element.

If you want to see the value of `elements[x]` in your debugger, use the expression `*(elements+x)`.

Comment: you could also just put `elements[x]` in the debugger.

Comment: Exactly this.  Your logic is fine, it's the output that's being misunderstood.

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, this is wrong:

```
temp[size] = size;
```

This will translate to:

```
temp[2] = 2;
```

And since arrays are zero-indexed you are writing outside your allocated area.

Comment: Ah! Curse the zero-indexing. That did end up being my problem, and I knew it was, but my inexperience with the debugger threw me off.

Answer (score 1):

The file `testnew.cpp` allocates memory for `size` elements in `temp` but then sets `temp[size]`, which is the `size+1` element.  Perhaps this should be

```
temp[i] = size;
```

The file `testalloc.cpp` commits the common error of reassigning memory to the same variable without verifying that thte call to `realloc` succeeds:

```
elements =(int *) realloc(elements,size * sizeof(int));
```

If `realloc` fails, `elements` will be set to null, and its original memory will be orphaned.

Answer (score 1):

First of all C++ is 0 indexed, so `temp[size] = size;` is an off by one error. And to answer your question, the type of elements is `int*`. That it's actually an array is not knowledge which is available to VS without code analysis. So, what you need to do is either use for example std::vector<>, boost::array or make sure that your array never detoriates to `int*`.