# (MSVC-2019) Is there a way to see the array's elements made with malloc in the debug(autos) screen?

Tags: arrays, c, debugging, visual-studio-2019

I recently learned how to use fscanf_s, While tinkering with fscanf_s I made a code that reads a file and save it into an array. (The file contains `123 12 41 234 5 12 45 1 5 764 232`)

First I made a piece of code to test if I made my While loop correctly

```
void arr_calc(FILE*f, ~~) {
    int i = 0, ~~;
    ...
    rewind(f);
    int arr[10];
    while (fscanf_s(f, "%d", &arr[i++]) != EOF);
}
```

When I checked the debug screen(autos), `arr` showed up like this

[image]

I could see what the `arr`was holding with this, But when I changed the `int arr[10]` into `malloc` to make a variable sized array like this

```
void arr_calc(FILE*f, ~~) {
    int i = 0, * arr, ~~;
    ...
    rewind(f);
    arr = (int*)malloc((count) * sizeof(int));
    while (fscanf_s(f, "%d", &arr[i++]) != EOF);
}
```

I couldn't figure out what `arr`was holding. - it only showed the first value

[image]

I presume that it has to do with the fact that I'm using a pointer for `arr` when I use `malloc`.

my question is: Is there a way that I can see the elements inside `arr` in the debug autos when using malloc(or realloc)?

If I said something wrong please correct me, Thank you

Comment: In the watch window add an expression like `arr,[count]`. You can see more in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/format-specifiers-in-cpp?view=vs-2019)

Comment: duplicates: [View array in Visual Studio debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/972511/995714), [Why does the debugger show only one element from my array pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9671591/995714)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display a dynamically allocated array in the Visual Studio debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75180/how-to-display-a-dynamically-allocated-array-in-the-visual-studio-debugger)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is normal and autos window cannot specify `malloc` type and it should work with the obvious definition size of your `arr`.

Instead, just as the community members said, use **Watch** Window, set `arr,10` to get that you want. And then it will parse the array with the input size.

[image]