# Watching each and every cell of a C++ Matrix in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, matrix, watch, eigen

I get an error like **CXX0059: Error: left operand is class not a function name** in VS2010, when i try to watch the values in columns and rows of my Jacobian Matrix.

For example; i have a matrix like

```
MatrixXf j = MatrixXf::Zero(2,mList.size());
...
...
   for(...)
   {
     j(0, col) += (-mList[i]->mLength*sin(angle));
     j(1, col) += ( mList[i]->mLength*cos(angle));
   }
```

and when i debugging this part, it fails to watch the variable j(0,col). I know, maybe it's not a function name, but it has some value in it. I mean, the matrix consists of 10 cells, but what i get from visual studio is only one float value.

Here is the sc of debug:

[image: debug screen]

Appreciate any help on watching the value of each cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `j(0, col)` construction calls overloaded `operator()()` on the class `MatrixXf`, such constructions are not evaluated by the debugger in native code. To view matrix's content, you should locate a pointer to the data inside the instance of `MatrixXf`. Most likely, it will have a `float*` type pointing to an array of data. By default, it is displayed in the debugger as a single float value. But you can specify its size manually as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972511/view-array-in-visual-studio-debugger) to expand an array, like this: `j.ptr,10`.

You can further enhance this approach by writing a special display rule in the `autoexp.dat` file. See a comprehensive tutorial [here](http://www.idigitalhouse.com/Blog/?p=83).