# displaying the middle of a large array while debugging

Tags: arrays, visual-studio-2010, debugging, range

I'm using C# with Visual Studio 2010. I've got a large array of floats (1M floats) and need to be able to look at small chunks of data in the middle of the array during debugging.

This can be done using the locals window, however the scroll bar maps onto 1M array elements, making it difficult to adjust the scroll bar with any precision.

Is there some way to look at, say k=688392 for f[k] to f[k+100] in the debugger?

Thanks

Comment: Check this post, it should help you out.  It explains how to see certain elements of an array when debugging in Visual Studios.  It should contain what you are looking for. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972511/view-array-in-visual-studio-debugger

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [immediate window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Just put a breakpoint after the line the values of the array are set and type `f[k]` in the immediate window and it will give you the value at that index.