# When declaring a new array using 'new int[n]' why doesn't it appear in locals list?

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [View array in Visual Studio debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972511/view-array-in-visual-studio-debugger)

I declare an array of 50 elements using:

```
int *ans;
ans = new int[50];
```

yet when I'm looking at the 'Locals' list and try to expand the array, it have only one
element, why's that? am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4):

The `locals` list just knows you have a pointer to an integer.  It doesn't have a good way to know how big that array is, unfortunately.  It could probably be made more sophisticated, or maybe you can create your own custom viewer for that variable - it depends on what IDE you're using probably.

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention I'm using Visual Studio 2012

Comment: @Quaker, sorry - I don't know anything about VS, personally.  Maybe there's a tip in the documentation.

Comment: For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972511/view-array-in-visual-studio-debugger