# operator new[] allocates only one element regardless of how many are requested (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, new-operator

For an introductory C++ course assignment (due tonight, of course!), I have to implement my own Vector class. Most everything seems to be working, except that I noticed in VS2012's debugger that it appears that only one element in _arr[] actually is being allocated. Regardless of the number (n) of elements requested, it only allocates a single element in the array. I followed the debug trace, and new[] is receiving 20 for the request (the requested 5 elements * 4 bytes for an int), but when I check sizeof(_arr) later, it only shows 4 bytes. Where did the other 16 bytes end up? Why are the other 4 elements missing? No errors are indicated, and no exceptions are thrown.

```
template <typename T>
void Vector<T>::Add ( const T& val )
{
    // Check if a new element would grow beyond the current allocation.
    if ( _length + 1 > _allocSize )
    {
        size_t n = 5; // <-- Set statically for this example
        // Create a new array of the requested size
        try
        {
            T* newArr = new (std::nothrow) T[n]();
            if( newArr == NULL )
                throw VectorException( VECTOR_CANNOT_GROW,
                     "Vector::Add", _length, n );
            // Copy the old array into the new array
            if( _length > 0 )
                for( size_t idx = 0; idx < _length; idx++ )
                    newArr[idx] = _arr[idx];
            // Delete any dynamic memory allocated to the old array.
            delete[] _arr;

            // Note: _sizeof(newArr) here indicates only 4 bytes!!!

            // Point _arr to the new array
            _arr = newArr;

            // Update the allocated size to the new array size
            _allocSize = n;
        }
        catch ( VectorException &cException )
        {
            cerr << cException.GetError() << endl;
            DoExit( cException.GetErrorNum() );
        }
    }
    // Add the new item to the end of the array and update the length.
    _arr[ _length++ ] = val;
}
```

Additionally, I have been able to use the Vectors as expected, but I'm afraid that I am actually just accessing memory outside of the array proper. It seems to be allocated to the program, but it does not show up in the array.

Or am I just getting confused, and there really is no problem at all?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What's the type of `_arr`? A pointer? If so, `sizeof(_arr)` is the size of a pointer.

Comment: "I noticed in VS2012's debugger that it appears that only one element in _arr[] actually is being allocated." This is a silly artifact of MSVS debugger: it treats your allocated array as a pointer, and shows only the initial element. You can safely ignore it.

Comment: You cannot use `sizeof` to get the number of array elements through a pointer. I suggest using `std::vector` even if you don't need to track the size of the array.

Comment: @DyP: This is a template, to _arr can be an array of anything. In my test cases, it has been tested with int, double, and chars.

Comment: If you call `delete[]` on `_arr`, then it probably isn't an array (an array would be, e.g. `int _arr[10];`). Maybe just show us the definition of `_arr`?

Comment: @Captain Oblivious - Whew! That makes me feel a lot better. Everything seemed to be working without problems, but that was a scary thing to notice. This counts as 25% of my grade, and a memory problem like that (if real) could be very bad! I am concerned about the sizeof() operator only showing 4 bytes though.

Comment: Re: "I am concerned about the sizeof() operator only showing 4 bytes though." Thanks for the link to the "Pointer array and sizeof confusion". Yes, that confirms my confusion on that part. Between the two, that really had me going. :-)

Comment: @Willscrlt `sizeof` is returning the size of the pointer not the number of element it points to. If you are on a 32bit system the pointer will be 4 bytes but for 64bit it's 8 bytes (generally speaking).

Comment: @DyP: Here's the private declaration for _arr within the Vector class:   T* _arr; // A dynamically allocated array holding objects of type T

Comment: As we all supposed, the type of `_arr` is `T*`, i.e., it's a pointer, not an array. The comment is a bit imprecise, it should rather say something like "points to a dynamically allocated array of objects of type T"

Comment: @DyP: Thanks. You are correct. I'm still a little weak on pointer terminology. That's why I'm still taking classes. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> when I check sizeof(_arr) later, it only shows 4 bytes

`sizeof` is a compile-time feature.  `new[]` allocates memory based on runtime parameters.  The end result is that `sizeof` doesn't have the information you're asking for.  Instead, it's telling you that a pointer to the array is 4 bytes, which is normal for 32 bit code.

`new[]` is correctly allocating the memory.  Unfortunately, the information you're looking for isn't available in standard C++ and your debugger is providing a misleading view of things.

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem.  sizeof(_arr) will always return 4 bytes, because it is really a pointer to an array.  Visual Studio's debugger can visualize the array contents [only if you tell it how many elements to display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972511/view-array-in-visual-studio-debugger).  Since you allocated the array dynamically, VS has no way of knowing how many elements to show, otherwise.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. It's annoying, but it makes sense. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The `sizeof` operator will tell you the size of the type or object that you pass to it. In this case it is a `T*`, and pointers are usually 32/64 bits (in your case it seems that you are building a 32bit binary). The result is unrelated to the amount of data that might be stored in the pointed buffer.

There are a couple of other weird things in your design and implementation... If it fails to allocate you call `DoExit` (exit the application?) but to get there you disable exceptions out of `new` by passing `std::nothrow`, only to test and throw your own exception that you catch a few lines later...

Why not catch `std::bad_alloc` directly? If you want to disable exceptions, why not act on the issue when you detect it instead of throwing just to catch a couple of lines later?

Comment: David, thanks for your comments. Yes, normally I would catch for bad_alloc, but since this is a class project (i.e., arbitrary rules in effect, not necessarily best practices), we are supposed to throw our own exceptions. Also, I omitted some other checks that also throw the same exception (all related to not being able to increase the vector size). Not ideal, but it works.