# Unexpected amount of symbols in watch after creating byte array dynamicly

Tags: c++, arrays

Could you please explain me, how should I understand following behavior:

```
typedef unsigned char byte;    
byte * test = new byte[8];
```

Here is the value of test I can see in the Watch: ÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍýýýý««««««««îþîþ

Why is it happening? Why I see 24 symbols, not 8?

Comment: You should accept one of the answers to close the question. If you are satisfied with the answer that is. I think your question has been answered correctly. For more information check out the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why the unexpected amount of symbols seen after dynamic memory allocation of array?

`test` refers to `c-string`. End of `c-string` is marked by `\0`.

`test` isn't explicitly initialized in the program posted in the question. `test` has *indeterminate value* and so you can't expect `\0` to be present exactly after the end of `c-string`.
The extra characters that you see in your debugger are those that exist between *the last character pointed to by `test`* and the first *`\0`* that the debugger found.

---

### Why it is said that `test` has indeterminate value?

When you use `new` as in below statement,

```
unsigned char *p_dynamic_alloc = new unsigned char[8];
```

a pointer to `unsigned char` is returned, which points to the address of the first element of the array. Dynamic memory of size: `8 * sizeof (unsigned char)` is allocated. Initializer is not mentioned.

Lets understand how `new` handles dynamic allocation without the initializer:

> [C++11: §5.3.4/15]: A *new-expression* that creates an object of type T initializes 
>       that object as follows:
>
> - If the *new-initializer* is omitted, the object is default-initialized (8.5); **if no initialization is performed, the object has indeterminate value.**
> - Otherwise, the *new-initializer* is interpreted according to the initialization rules of 8.5 for direct-initialization.

Lets understand if it is really default initialized or if no initialization is performed.

Default initialization (of an `unsigned char*`) is stated as,

> [C++11: §8.5/7]:To default-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualiﬁed) class type (Clause 9), the default constructor (12.1) or T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed  if T has no default constructor or overload resolution (13.3) results in an ambiguity or in a function that is deleted or inaccessible from the context of the initialization);
> - if T is an array type, each element is default-initialized;
> - **otherwise, no initialization is performed.**

which means as pointed out earlier, **the object has indeterminate value.**

---

### Solution

Properly initialize your dynamic byte array:

```
byte *test = new byte[8]();
```

Comment: But still, when I declare a couple of such variables I always see the same characters "between the last character pointed to by test and the first \0 that the debugger found". Why?

Comment: Looks like your debugger uses the same (garbage)value for all the _uninitialized_ objects to let the programmer know the problem. Please update your question with the Compiler, Debugger and additional related details that you are using.

Answer (score 3):

Since you allocated the array dynamically, the debugger doesn't know from the type how big the array is. Some compilers (e.g. Visual Studio) allow special expressions to interpret a pointer as an array (see e.g. [View array in Visual Studio debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972511/view-array-in-visual-studio-debugger)), in your case, you could try

```
test,8
```

And you should see only the 8 values of test. However, the shown values won't make more sense, since they're still uninitialized after the snippet you show.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I had a thought, that all extra characters I see just are in memory consequentially after my 8 bytes, but why then are they always the same?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what "the Watch" is (something in your debugger perhaps?), but given just a pointer it has no way of knowing how much memory you've allocated. Probably, it assumes that the pointer refers to a C-style string of printable characters followed by a zero terminator, and displays all the memory it finds until it reaches a zero-valued byte.

Answer (score 1):

Studio is treating `test` as a C string, an array of characters terminated by `\0`. It will not impact the functioning of your program, it is just the debugger trying to be smart.

Answer (score 1):

Because your visualiser works with your array as it was array of chars. It tries to display it as a string which is supposed to end with '\0'.

So what you see is uninitialized memory.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `test` is *uninitialised* and you shouldn't worry what it is.