# VS2013 Mixed mode debugger doesn't show Pointer values

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

[It says everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972511/view-array-in-visual-studio-debugger) that all you need to do is add a comma and number of arrays to view pointer info, however I find I can't see any values in the watch window at all, and attempting "RawPacket,1" only tells me **'1' is not a valid format specifier**.  I don't understand, as vs2008 showed these without any trouble.

The project is mixed mode, VB , c# and vc++, targeting 4.0 framework.

For those who want to know, here is more info about what raw packet is.

```
typedef union {
    _AgalertAsciiPacket Legacy;
    _PacketHeader Header;
    char RawData[1];
    struct {
        _PacketHeader Header;
        _PayloadGps Payload;
    }GPS;

    struct {
        _PacketHeader Header;
        _PayloadStatus Payload;
    }Status;

} _RawPacket;
```

Defined like :

```
public ref class Packet{
   _RawPacket * RawPacket;
   Packet(){
   RawPacket = new _RawPacket;
   }
//etc, etc
}
```

Watch window
[image: Watch window]!

Tools->options
[image: Tools options]!

Comment: Too many screenshots, not enough real info.  What is a "RawPacket"?  Turn on the Managed Compatibility Mode option in mixed mode debugging.

Comment: How is one supposed to ask, anyway?  The most basic of debugger functions isn't working here, so where to start?  Use netbeans maybe?  Mixed mode option is on, same results.

Comment: Adding to the waterfall that is stackoverflow, I think I have asked 5 or 6 questions here over the years, perhaps I have made progress, this one at least got one comment.

Comment: After time, restarting visual studio, changing to mixed mode, now it is working.