# Use unique_ptr for an array, how to view each value in debug mode "local" or "watch" tags

Tags: c++, c++11

below are simple commands. what should I do to view the every array value in debug mode?

```
    int N=3;
    unique_ptr<int []> I(new int[N]());

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {   
         I[i]=i*3;  
    }
```

Comment: You should tag it with [tag:visual-studio], I guess?

Comment: Yes, VC 2012. With suggestion from Alter I can see those values now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the IDE to be visual studio. When you hit a breakpoint where `I` is in scope, open a Watch window and type `I.get(),3` into a new row. `get()` gives you the raw `int*` pointer and `3` displays it in the watch as an `int[3]` array, with all its values listed.

[image: Watch unique_ptr array example VS2017]

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972511/view-array-in-visual-studio-debugger). This appears to work with frame pointers both turned on and off.

Answer (score 0):

Compiling [with frame pointers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/oy-frame-pointer-omission?view=vs-2017) will help quite a bit. Without them, debugging won't be able to identify the locations of local variables that have been elided by removing them on x86 executables.